# Angular update ng-model via $broadcast event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to update a ng-model value from an event which occurred in some-other place. First what i did is broadcasting an event to a directive

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('updateModel');
```

and in the directive i did a naive code to update a model

```
    restrict:'A',
          require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes,ngModel,ngModelCtrl) {
              scope.updateVal=function(){
                ngModel.$setViewValue('');
                    ngModel.$setPristine();
              }
              scope.$on('updateModel',function(){
                  scope.updateVal();

              })
        }
```

issue here is it's updating all the model, i want it to restrict to a particular model. How to achieve this

Comment: include html code also

Comment: create a fiddle and provide us the link.